# Clear setFillAfter() on android

Tags: android

I am animating a view using translate animation. I've used setFillAfter(true) and it animates successfully.

My code is.

```
final ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lamb);
        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        image.startAnimation(animation);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
        {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {     }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {    }
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                Handler ss = new Handler();
                ss.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                } ,4000);
            }
        });
```

I use a Handler for hiding the image view after 4 seconds, but it does not hide. How can I hide the image after some time?

After the animation ends, I want to show the image on the last position that it was so I use setFillAfter(true);  after 4 seconds I hide the image view.

How can I make the image invisible?

Comment: where did you put view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set AnimationListener. And when animation will end, make the view invisible.

```
moveForward.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

});
```

Comment: sorry, small mistake.. updated.. set AnimationListener to animation moveForward..

Answer (score 0):

image.clearAniamtion(), before setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)